# How to convert double to same value without decimal point

Tags: java

I want to remove the decimal point from double?

Ex: 234.567 will become 234567.

Comment: Did you try anything? at-least Google?

Comment: `.toString().replace(".", "")`?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this...?  You will get wildly different values for arbitrary differences in precision.

Comment: This is what I've tried but it contains error.
I have so many numbers like this and the decimal point is located random.

Comment: Double point = "8233.33";
   point = point.replace(".", "");
   System.out.println(point);

Comment: o that annoying decimal point. Who needs it anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `String.valueOf` method and then replace `.` with a blank character(`""`).

```
String s = String.valueOf(234.567).replace(".","");
```

Comment: have fun when converting back to int\long :). example 9999.99999999999999. you will still need to use double to store the result as numeric.

Comment: @UmNyobe this is what OP needs an he didn't mention that he waht to convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

Use a easy way out. 
Cast it to int. :P

> x = (float) 5.12;
>             int a = (int) x;
>             System.out.println(a);

Comment: It's a very bad idea. It will rip of all post decimal values, and this is not what OP wants.

Comment: It removes the value after decimal. I know it is not a very good idea to cast, but it solves the purpose isn't it?

Comment: @LPD Yes it will solve the purpose if you don't care about numbers after decimal point.

Comment: @LPD the question makes it look like the OP wants the numbers after the decimal